# Operand type clash: my first User Defined Type with list of Integers, how to test via SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-type

I found this wonderful code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure)

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE(
    [Item] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
);

    GO 
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UseStringList]
        @list StringList READONLY
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Just return the items we passed in
        SELECT l.Item FROM @list l;
    END

    GO
```

but I dont know how to test it via SSMS please

```
declare @list   StringList  = '1,2,3,4,5'
exec sp_UseStringList @list
```

gives the error:

```
Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with StringList
```

How can I test the list '1,2,3,4,5' please

Comment: '1,2,3,4,5' is not a StringList...It is expecting a Table, as you've declared it  `CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE`

Comment: I still dont understand the jist of this please. I can create a table, insert the values, but how to execute please, this still gives error .declare ATlist      as table(l nvarchar(max))
insert Into ATlist(l)values('1,2,3,4,5')
exec sp_UseStringList ATlist

Comment: [Please don't use the `sp_` prefix](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What does "test the list" mean? Are you trying to turn the string `'1,2,3,4,5'` into a table as a list of integers, e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I couldn't quite work that out myself. I believe the question is something to do with passing a  List<string> from C# to a SQL proc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have declared `dbo.StringList` to be a User-Defined **Table** Type, you have to utilise it as you would a table.

So instead of assigning `'1,2,3,4,5'` as a string, you must `INSERT` this value into the table.

There's a [pretty decent example in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489.aspx), but I'll create one based on your example above.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[StringList] AS TABLE(
  [Item] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
);

GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UseStringList]
    @list StringList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- Just return the items we passed in
    SELECT l.Item FROM @list l;
END

GO


DECLARE @StringList StringList

INSERT Into @StringList values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5') 

EXEC sp_UseStringList @StringList
```